# $route.reload() is causing controller to execute twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

we have route config

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/Search', { templateUrl: 'Search.html', controller: 'SearchCtrl' })
   .when('/Accounts', { templateUrl: 'Accounts.html', controller: 'AccountsCtrl' })
   .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Search' });
```

in controller have btn click which is reloading route

```
$location.path("/Accounts").search({
      AccountOrShortName: i.AccountOrShortName,
});           
$route.reload();
```

`AccountsCtrl` is getting executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, Your code 100% surly load the controller many more time

1st time) When button click

2nd time ) When this line call `$route.reload();`// This code reload the page

3rd,4th,5th...,n time)The page will load, Whenever `$route.reload();` code call

So, You should be call return false before reload the page second time.